# Renewed codesign certificate shows keychain authorization dialog

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain

My app stores items in the Mac's keychain. I made sure I signed the app using a code signing certificate so that my users aren't bothered by keychain authorization dialogs everytime I update the app.

The problem is: The code sign certificate was only valid for one year and I had to renew the certificate recently. I want to release a new update now which will be signed using the renewed certificate. When I install the update, keychain no longer trusts the app and shows the authorization dialog.

Is there a way to avoid this? If not, is there anything I can do to avoid this the next time my cert expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to avoid this. The CA generates a completely new cert even when renewing old certificates. My 'solution' is to apply for a longer code signing certificate - 3 years.